# wordpress redirect on iis

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

We have moved our company website from http to https and also changed the domain. I am struggling to change our blog from http://blog.oldwesite.co.za to https://www.newwebsite.co.za/blog

What do I need to put in my .htaccess for this to work?

I have tried this:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blog.oldwebsite.co.za$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newwebsite.co.za/blog%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

but it is not working. We are hosting on IIS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Since your server can parse PHP, why don't you just create an `index.php` file on your old server root and put this

```
<?php
    die( header( 'Location: https://www.newwebsite.co.za/blog', true, 301 ) );
?>
```

'nother one you can find on the NET: [source](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess#old-domain-to-new)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.old.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Let me check this and will update if it works. thanks